# This array is fixed or temporarily locked

Tags: vba, vb6

I am using split function and assigning the value in a variable and running the code in loop after few iterations its giving an error of "This array is fixed or temporarily locked (Visual Basic)"..

e.g; here value of movies_cat1 read from excel is in form of this------
"Movies->List All Movies , Movies->World Cinema->Asia , Movies->Movies by Language->Sinhalese , Movies->Drama"

```
For crow = 1 To 100

    Value = Worksheets("Movies_categories").Range("A" & crow).Value
    cat_final = Worksheets("Movies_categories").Range("B" & crow).Value

    If Value = "y" Or Value = "Y" Then

      'Loop for reading the data from tabsheet- Movies

      For crowss = 5 To 3000
        movies_cat1 = Worksheets("Movies").Range("B" & crowss).Value
        movies_language = Worksheets("Movies").Range("C" & crowss).Value

        If movies_language = "English" Then

          Temp = Split(movies_cat, ",")  'run time Error:10  occurs here..

          For Each boken_c In Temp
            flag = 0
            boken_c = Trim(boken_c)

            If RTrim(LTrim(boken_c)) = LTrim(RTrim(cat_final)) Then
              flag = 1
              GoTo Line4:
            End If
          Next boken_c
        End If
      Next crowss
    End If
Line4:    Next crow
```

Error occurs at this statement: `Temp = Split(movies_cat, ",")`, it says that the array is fixed or temporarily locked, because i think initially its taking 'temp' as a variable, but while returning the value of split function, variable 'Temp' becomes array after completion of first loop(i.e after crow = 6,7....)

Comment: What live gives the error? Also, if you indent your code properly, it will be easier for us to read.

Comment: Where is movies_cat defined?  You should try using **option explicit** in your modules...

Comment: How did you Dim the `Temp` variable? Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the `Temp = ...` line and watching the status of `Temp` and `movies_cat`?

Comment: My answer has been updated. (Oh, and try using more meaningful variable names)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `line4` label is outside the for loop on the temp variable so when you `goto` it leaves it locked.

You really should restructure your code to not use a goto inside the for each loop.

Maybe:

```
For crow = 1 To 100 

  Value = Worksheets("Movies_categories").Range("A" & crow).Value 
  cat_final = Worksheets("Movies_categories").Range("B" & crow).Value 

  If Value = "y" Or Value = "Y" Then 

    'Loop for reading the data from tabsheet- Movies 

    For crowss = 5 To 3000 
      movies_cat1 = Worksheets("Movies").Range("B" & crowss).Value 
      movies_language = Worksheets("Movies").Range("C" & crowss).Value 

      If movies_language = "English" Then 

        Temp = Split(movies_cat, ",")  'run time Error:10  occurs here.. 

        For Each boken_c In Temp 
          flag = 0 
          boken_c = Trim(boken_c) 

          If RTrim(LTrim(boken_c)) = LTrim(RTrim(cat_final)) Then 
            flag = 1 
            **Exit For**
          End If
          **If flag = 1 Then Exit For**
        Next boken_c 
      End If 
      **If flag = 1 Then Exit For**
    Next crowss 
  End If 
Next crow
```

(Note the **d lines.)

Comment: @user930679 It looks to me like you need an Exit For rather than a GoTo - these are generally not a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too with VBA.  I cannot say I am proud of how I managed to get it, but it is supplied here just in can anyone else accidentally slips up on this.

It is quite interesting to debug as the failure occurs at the call to a sub or function - not at the point of failure.  Luckily, you can follow the code through to the offending line of the called routine before it reports the error.

```
Call Sub1(gArray(3))
debug.print gArray(3)
...
Sub Sub1(i as integer)
Redim gArray(0)
End sub
```

Clearly the VB RT is not going to like this as by the time the debug.print executes, the array dimension does not exist.  Ok why the hell would you want to pass a globally declared array anyway?  Guilty as charged.

So in the example above you get the error at **the call** to Sub1, but the thing causing it is the Redim in the sub.

The moral to the story is do not pass global variables as parameters to subs.  Another simple fix is to declare the Sub1 slightly differently:

```
Sub Sub1(ByVal i as integer)
```

This means the `i` variable is copied (but not returned) by the Sub.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Deanna for the answer! I have a similar message on `ReDim Preserve` statement at the last line in next fragment of code:

```
        If StrComp(Mid(s, 1, lE), txtE, vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
            For i = iMdl To 1 Step -1
                With blks(i)
                    If .lnEnd = 0 Then   ' ".lnEnd" is a member of blks(i)
                        .lnEnd = ln
                        GoTo NXT
                    End If
                End With
            Next
            errBegWith = errBegWith & ln & ", "
NXT:
        End If
    '...
    ReDim Preserve blks(iMdl)
```

And after extracting assignment `.lnEnd = ln` from inside of the `With` the program works fine:

```
        If StrComp(Mid(s, 1, lE), txtE, vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
            For i = iMdl To 1 Step -1
                If blks(i).lnEnd = 0 Then
                    blks(i).lnEnd = ln
                    GoTo NXT
                End If
            Next
            errBegWith = errBegWith & ln & ", "
NXT:
        End If
    '...
    ReDim Preserve blks(iMdl)
```